# FindStringSubmatch returns matched group twice

Tags: go

Perhaps I'm missing something very basic about the go's `regexp.FindStringSubmatch()`. I want to capture the group with all digits that follows the string `"Serial Number: "` but get unexpected output. My code is as below:

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {

    x := "Serial Number: 12334"
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`(\d+)`)
    res := r.FindStringSubmatch(x)

    for i,val := range res {
        fmt.Printf("entry %d:%s\n", i,val)
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
entry 0:12334
entry 1:12334
```

I'm more familiar with python's grouping that seems pretty straight-forward:

```
>>> re.search('(\d+)', "Serial Number: 12344").groups()[0]
'12344'
```

How can I get the grouping to work in go?
thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [`Regexp.FindStringSubmatch`](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindStringSubmatch):

> `FindStringSubmatch` returns a slice of strings holding the text of the leftmost match of the regular expression in s and the matches

So:

- the first entry is what has been matched: '`12334`' (leftmost match)
- the second entry is the one captured group: '`12334`'

Another example:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("a(x*)b(y|z)c")
fmt.Printf("%q\n", re.FindStringSubmatch("-axxxbyc-"))
```

That would print:

- the leftmost match: `"axxxbyc"`
- the two captured groups: `"xxx" "y"`

Comment: Thanks. So the capture group is always the last element in the slice, i.e `res[1]` in my case?

Comment: The first captured group is `res[1]`, the second captured group is `res[2]`, and so on. Only `res[0]` is special and represents not a group but the leftmost match.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I was going crazy for a bit.